# Datagridview Checkbox Change Row Color

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview, colors

I am changing a row color depending if a checkbox is clicked. If the checkbox is clicked, the row is considered as "Critical" therefore I call a method that applies a red color to it.

---

```
Private Sub dgvAssemblies_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvAssemblies.CellContentClick, dgvExpeditions.CellContentClick, dgvMachines.CellContentClick
    Dim s As DataGridView = sender
    If s.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = s.Name.Remove(0, 3) & "ColChkCritical" Then
        If s.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value Then
            FormatRowColor(s.Rows(e.RowIndex), "Critical")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The following code calls the "FormatRowColor" method which accepts the row and state as parameters. That part works correctly. The issue is as soon as I click the checkbox, the row doesn't change colors.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a portion of code. After some research, I found [this source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

For clicks in a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`, this event occurs before the check box changes value, so if you do not want to calculate the expected value based on the current value, you will typically handle the `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` event instead. Because that event occurs only when the user-specified value is committed, which typically occurs when focus leaves the cell, you must also handle the `DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event. In that handler, if the current cell is a check box cell, call the `DataGridView.CommitEdit` method and pass in the Commit value.

### CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged

Occurs when the state of a cell changes in relation to a change in its contents.

```
Private Sub dgvAssemblies_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgvAssemblies.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, dgvExpeditions.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged, dgvMachines.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If sender.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
        sender.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub
```